# How to send new geolocalization request and refresh the Google map while typing address on input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to refresh Google Map and send new geolocalization request without refreshing the page and while user typing address (city and address, country is constant) on input. How can I do that?

```
<input type="text" id="input_adress" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function mapk() {
//code about start the map (new google.maps.Map)...
geokoder.geocode({address: 'UK'}, start_geocode);
}
function start_geocode(var1, status) {    
//more code...    
</script>
```

And now is the code from which I want to start:

```
$(function()
   {$('#input_adress').keyup(function() {

       });
   });
```

I'm not sure what should next? Probably I need to select the map first...

```
geokoder.geocode({address: 'UK '+$('#input_adress').val()}, start_geocode);
```

I have jQuery library on my page. Is this enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    geocoder.geocode({'address': $('#input_address').val()}, function(results, status) {
        setMap(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
    })
});

function setMap(lat, lng) {
    map_location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    marker.setPosition(map_location);
    map.setCenter(map_location);
}
```

this uses `click` on a button to search but you could use keypress / change on the input.

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/KmR55/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Ussually for live search/query what I do is monitor the keydown on the user input, when there is a pause indicate the user is finish typing then I would process the user input.

onkeydown:

`clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(function(){ process(); }, 500);`